# How to animate camera.zoom in three.js with

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, tween.js

How to animate the zoom of camera in three.js with orthigraphic camera.
Without animation it is very simple. I only have to set `camera.zoom = 1`. 
But I want to animate it with tween.js.

There is my codePen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yVOOLj?editors=1111

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(640 / -2, 640 / 2, 380 / 2, 380 / -2, -5000, 5000);
camera.position.set(100,100,100);
camera.zoom = 0.1;


var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( 640, 380 );
renderer.setClearColor("#FFF");
$("#canvas").append( renderer.domElement );

var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 100, 100, 100 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x00ff00} );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

var originAxes = new THREE.AxisHelper(1200);
scene.add(originAxes); 

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement, renderer, scene);

animate();

function animate(){
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  TWEEN.update();
  render();
}

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};


$("#withoutAnim").click(function () {
  camera.zoom = 1;    
});

$("#withAnim").click(function () { 
  var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(0).to(1,  500);
  tween.onUpdate(function () {
    camera.zoom = 0.10;
  });
  tween.start();
  
});
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
#canvas {float: left; width: 640px; height: 380px; border: 1px solid #d3d3d3 }
.button { border: 1px solid black; cursor: pointer; width: 230px; height: 20px;}
.button:hover{background: blue; color: white;}
```

```html
<script src="http://sole.github.io/tween.js/build/tween.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>

<div id="canvas">
<div id="withoutAnim" class="button" >working zoom without animation</div>
<div id="withAnim" class="button" >zoom with animation - not working</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to put it like that then (without global variables):

```
$("#withAnim").click(function() {
  var zoom = {
    value: camera.zoom // from current zoom (no matter if it's more or less than 1)
  };
  var zoomEnd = {
    value: 1 // to the zoom of 1
  };
  var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(zoom).to(zoomEnd, 500); // duration of tweening is 0.5 second
  tween.onUpdate(function() {
    camera.zoom = zoom.value;
  });
  tween.start();
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/p2rf5etq/) example

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That works almost perfectly. But is it possible to start the zoom with the current zoom value, to zoom in if the current zoom value is higher than the final value of zoom and zoom out if the current zoom value is smaller than the final value of zoom?

Comment: Is `TWEEN` part of three.js?

Comment: @Jeff No, but it's [included](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/libs/tween.min.js) in its distributive.