# WebGL (Three.js) canvas zoom in and out with mousewheel

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, three.js

I am working with WebGL (Three.js) to experiment with rendering 3D scenes within an Angular app.
One thing that I want to do, is allow for the mousewheel events to be overridden so that they zoom the canvas in and out instead of the entire window. I've started by attempting to disable the `mousewheel` and `mousedown` event listeners but they seem to be responding to the event listeners. How do I get it to zoom in and out of the canvas, instead of the entire window?

My code is available here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hwzz3r.

```
  animate() {
    // We have to run this outside angular zones,
    // because it could trigger heavy changeDetection cycles.
    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {
        this.render();
      } else {
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
          this.render();
        });
      }
      window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        this.resize();
      });
      window.addEventListener('mousewheel', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
      }, false);
      window.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
      }, false);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Remember that "it doesn't seem to be working" is not a problem description. What did you expect it to do, and what did it do instead? One thing to note is that you seem to have added your event listeners for those mouse events to `window` instead of specifically the canvas element this should apply to, so you probably want to switch that.

Comment: Also remember that external links turn into dead links over time, so if that link has code that's relevant to the question: remember to put that in your post, even if you give people a link to the live version (event better: reduce your example to an [mcve] so folks can see the actual problem in concise, full code)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m5jwht) work for you?

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov this works great!

Comment: Nice, I'll post why it works tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, [`mousewheel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousewheel_event) is nonstandard and deprecated, you should use [`wheel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/wheel_event) event.

The [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method can take optional second argument which can be an object containing `passive` key. Here is what [`passive`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#:%7E:text=passive) option is:

> A `Boolean` that, if `true`, indicates that the function specified by listener will never call `preventDefault()`. If a passive listener does call `preventDefault()`, the user agent will do nothing other than generate a console warning.

There is note at [Improving scrolling performance with passive listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Improving_scrolling_performance_with_passive_listeners) and it states:

> According to the specification, the default value for the `passive` option is always `false`. However, this introduces the potential for event listeners handling certain touch events (among others) to block the browser's main thread while it is attempting to handle scrolling, resulting in possibly enormous reduction in performance during scroll handling.
>
> To prevent this problem, some browsers (specifically, Chrome and Firefox) have changed the default value of the `passive` option to `true` for the `touchstart` and `touchmove` events on the document-level nodes `Window`, `Document`, and `Document.body`. This prevents the event listener from being called, so it can't block page rendering while the user is scrolling.

Even though there is no mention of `wheel`/`mousewheel` there, that is true for those events as well. You can see this at [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Browser_compatibility) table.

In a nutshell, in order to be able to use `preventDefault` for wheel event in some browsers, you have to pass `{ passive: false }` option for `addEventListener`:

```
window.addEventListener('wheel', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
}, { passive: false });
```

---

For zooming in/out you can use [`PerspectiveCamera.zoom`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.zoom) and [`WheelEvent.deltaY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent/deltaY) like so:

```
window.addEventListener('wheel', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault(); /// prevent scrolling
  
  let zoom = this.camera.zoom; // take current zoom value
  zoom += event.deltaY * -0.01; /// adjust it
  zoom = Math.min(Math.max(.125, zoom), 4); /// clamp the value

  this.camera.zoom = zoom /// assign new zoom value
  this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix(); /// make the changes take effect
}, { passive: false });
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Extremely helpful.  One thing I didn't get was how do you decide between zooming in and zooming out. Like for example, if a user pressed the plus key, how would the same event listener be used to zoom in specifically.

Comment: `event.deltaY` can be negative or positive depending on the scroll direction that's how it differentiates. Just create a method pass in the adjustment amount, negative or positive `adjustZoomBy(0.1)`. See [this sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m5jwht?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcanvas%2Fcanvas.service.ts). But for smoothness, you may need to use interpolation. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40706130/how-to-animate-camera-zoom-in-three-js-with)